# Using Paperclip and MiniExiftool to scrape exif data for photos and videos

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm using Rails 3.0.7, Ruby 1.9.2, and Paperclip 2.7 w/the MiniExiftool gem to scrape the data from uploaded photos and videos then store that data as serialized json in the DB; ultimately so I can use IM/FFMPEG to rotate photos/videos as needed.

Unfortunately I'm not having much luck.  Whenever I try to instantiate the MiniExiftool using MiniExiftool.new on the original file (using model.photo.queued_for_write[:original]), the MiniExiftool gem throws an exception at lib/mini_exiftool.rb:90:in `load' because the file is either open for read or just not there.

I've put the code in several places: the paperclip post process hook, a paperclip processor, and in delayed job.  I can't seem to get anything to work.  My fallback plan was to run a delayed job ~15 seconds after upload and download the file using model.photo.to_file, run mini exif, store the exif data and process accordingly (i.e. rotate based on exif rotation data when necessary).  However that solution hasn't worked thus far because MiniExiftool throws the exact same error with the file that was downloaded via model.photo.to_file.

Has anyone else tried to do this exact thing or something very similar?  Seems like a common need when trying to process photo/video uploads.

Any help is appreciated!  Thanks.

Louis

Comment: So I figured out why I wasn't able to use MiniExiftool after model.photo.to_file. I'm on Windows (I know, I know) and my Nginx temp location is my short form user profile directory, which MiniExiftool did not like. Therefore, once I changed it to c:\temp, and Paperclip's to_file method downloaded my S3 files there everything started working great!

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
class Picture < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_post_process :save_exif_data

  def save_exif_data
    exif_data = MiniExiftool.new(image.queued_for_write[:original].path)
    self.serialized_json = exif_data.attributes
  end
end
```

You can see an implementation of it here: http://listenin.gs/2014/07/18/using-miniexiftool-with-paperclip/